# TCL : Why expr manipulating the numbers bigger than 0xffffffff without telling to the interpretor it is a long?

Tags: tcl

## STEP-1

```
% expr 0xffffffffff
1099511627775
%
%
```

## STEP-2

```
% format %i 0xffffffffff
-1
```

## STEP-3

```
% format %li 0xffffffffff
1099511627775
%
```

## STEP-1

Observe carefully the above steps expr is able to manibulating more than 32 Byte numbers wihtout telling to the TCL interpretor specially in the .

## STEP-2

Here format command is unable to manupulating the same .

## STEP-3

Here `format` command is able to manipulating after telling the interpretor that it is a long (by declaring `'l'` (el)) .

How the `expr` command is manipulating it . I am Using TCL version 8.5.

Comment: abitiary big integers. The string representation of an integer is always base 10.

Comment: Can you elaborate the comment please ?

Answer (score 4):

Tcl 8.5 gained support for arbitrary length integers (based on the modified code of the `libtommath` library) which works like this: until your integers fit into their platform-native size, the math operations are done using "plain" integers, and when the interpreter detects the result of an operation is about to overflow the platform's integer size, the resulting Tcl value will be represented by a synthetic arbitrary-sized integer instead.  All this happes transparently.

The crucial thing to understand before reading further is that when Tcl is about to interpret a value as an integer *without* any explicit specification of its real type, the resulting integer will be signed.

Now when you run `expr 0xffffffffff` in an *interactive* interpreter, the Tcl shell needs to show you the result of running `expr`, and this means *converting it to a string* first. Since this is a *default* conversion (that is, you do not have any control over it<sup>1</sup>), it just takes your arbitrary-length integer and formats it — as a signed integer.

When you do *explicit* conversion to a string using the `format` command, the latter interprets the value passed to it according to the matching format string specification, so if you tell it you have a 32-bit integer, `format` interprets it as that, and if you tell it you have a 64-bit integer, the same thing happens.  Obviously, the results will be different.

---

<sup>1</sup> Short of manipulating the `tcl_precision` global variable but this does not apply to our case.